# Conventions for graded wedge product in supergeometry

Tags: differential-geometry, conventions, supersymmetry, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

There are two conventions for the graded exterior product on superspace (see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/signs+in+supergeometry):

$$\alpha \wedge \beta = (-1)^{pq+|\alpha||\beta|}\beta\wedge\alpha \;(\text{Deligne})\tag{1}$$
$$\alpha \wedge \beta = (-1)^{(p+|\alpha|)(q+|\beta|)}\beta\wedge\alpha \;\;(\text{Bernstein})\tag{2}$$

for a $p$-form $\alpha$ and a $q$-form $\beta$, while $|\cdot|$ represents the Grassmann parity. On the other hand, there are two possibilities for the exterior derivative, depending on whether or not it changes the parity of forms. Thus, for supercoordinates $z^A$ we have:
$$
|d|=0 \;\Rightarrow \; |dz^A|=|z^A|, \quad  
|d|=1 \;\Rightarrow \; |dz^A|=|z^A|+1.\tag{3}
$$
I read in [this](https://orbilu.uni.lu/bitstream/10993/14295/1/LecturesSupergeometryFinalRevised.pdf) and [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0211280) references that the cases $|d|=0$ and $|d|=1$ correspond to the Deligne and Bernstein conventions, respectively; but for the $|d|=1$ case it seems not to hold if we consider $\alpha=dz^A$ and $\beta=dz^B$, since for this case $p=1=q$ and $|\alpha|=|z^A|+1,$  $|\beta|=|z^B|+1$ and thus we get $$dz^A\wedge dz^B = (-1)^{|z^A||z^B|}dz^B\wedge dz^A ,\tag{4}$$ meanwhile in the literature we commonly found:
$$
\;dz^A\wedge dz^B = (-1)^{1+|z^A||z^B|}dz^B\wedge dz^A \;\;(\text{Deligne}) \tag{5} $$
$$\;dz^A\wedge dz^B = (-1)^{(1+|z^A|)(1+|z^B|)}dz^B\wedge dz^A \;\;(\text{Bernstein}).\tag{6}
$$
What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: The confusion seems to be that the notation $|\cdot|$ somewhat misleadingly sometimes denotes the Grassmann-grading and sometimes the total grading.

1. In the Deligne convention $|d|_g=0$, the form-degree $|\cdot|_f$ and the Grassmann-grading $|\cdot|_g$ are two *independent* gradings. This leads to eqs. (1) & (5).
2. In the Bernstein convention $|d|=1$, the total grading
   $$|\cdot|~=~|\cdot|_f+|\cdot|_g$$
   (which determines the Koszul/permutation sign) is the *sum* of the form-degree $|\cdot|_f$ and the Grassmann-grading $|\cdot|_g$. This leads to eqs. (2) & (6).

If this sounds crazy, then consider the following sanity-check: Go to the purely bosonic case with no Grassmann-odd objects. Then the Deligne & Bernstein conventions should preferably collapse to the same standard [exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) for [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form).

Comment: Focusing only on the Bernstein convention, for the $1-$form $dz^A$ we have that its Grassmann-grading is $|z^A|+1,$ while its form-degree is $1.$ Hence, the total grading will be just $|z^A|,$ similarly for $dz^B.$ With this we would not get equation $(6).$

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: It seems that my point was not clear enough. Equation (6) obeys the total grading reasoning whenever the Grassmann-grading of the $1-$form $dz^A$ coincides with the Grassmann-grading of the coordinate $z^A;$ but it is assumed that $|d|=1$ (Bernstein convention), what it means that the application of the exterior derivative $d$ changes the Grassman-grading of any pure form. Perhaps the error lies in the assumption that the case of an odd exterior derivative corresponds to Bernstein convention.